# Remove characters with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file containing these lines :

```
  1 1b0c1375c901dc8b3cc162010dc2691ca256c765
  1 1b0c19c226e87899a0060e058e366fbbf4148ab4
  1 1b0d1bb9f81763c679b54eac9e816a5e45dace79
  1 1b0d59faa9f62150a38670c59599bdc31f3094b5
  1 1b0d6a8132667ce07d7479913a85ec057331a816
```

in general :

I would like to tranform them in thhis format :

```
1,1b0c1375c901dc8b3cc162010dc2691ca256c765
1,1b0c19c226e87899a0060e058e366fbbf4148ab4
1,1b0d1bb9f81763c679b54eac9e816a5e45dace79
1,1b0d59faa9f62150a38670c59599bdc31f3094b5
1,1b0d6a8132667ce07d7479913a85ec057331a816
```

I have already tried this command line but couldn't success:

```
sed 's/^  *\([0-9]*\) \([0-9a-zA-Z]*\)$/\1,\2/' file
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 0):

Given that the input is *field-based*, `awk` allows for a simple solution:

```
awk -v OFS=, '$2=$2' file
```

- `awk` by default breaks input lines into fields by runs of whitespace, trimming leading and trailing runs.
- Thus, `$1` refers to the input file's 1st column, and `$2` to the 2nd.
- `-v OFS=,` tells `awk` to separate the fields with `,` *on output* (special variable `OFS` is the **o**utput **f**ield **s**eparator).
- `$2=$2` is a dummy assignment that has an important side effect, however: it causes `awk` to rebuild the line at hand from its constituent field using `OFS` as the separator.
- Because the result of the assignment is a nonempty string other than `0`, the assignment is considered to be (conceptually) *true* in a Boolen context, which an expression outside `{...}` is - it is a *pattern*, in Awk terminology.
- A pattern that evaluates to *true* that has no  associated *action* (`{ ... }`) by default simply *prints* the - rebuilt with `,`-separated fields - line at hand.

---

As for **what you tried**:

```
sed 's/^ ([0-9]) ([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$/\1,\2/' file  # DOESN'T WORK
```

- You're only matching *1* space at the beginning of the line, whereas your input has *multiple* ones.
- By default - and in line with POSIX - `sed` only supports *basic* regular expressions, where - counter-intuitively, these days - capture-group enclosing `(` and `)` must be represented as `\(` and `\)`.

A POSIX-compliant reformulation would therefore be:

```
sed 's/^ *\([0-9]\) \([0-9a-zA-Z]*\)$/\1,\2/' file
```

If you're on Linux (*GNU* `sed`) or BSD/macOS, however, you can use option `-E` to enable modern *extended* regular expressions, where `(` and `)` work as expected:

```
sed -E 's/^ *([0-9]) ([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$/\1,\2/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I guess, sed not working because of lack of consideration about some spaces

```
sed -e 's/..\([0-9]\)\{1\} \([0-9a-zA-Z]*\)$/\1,\2/g' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are blank space in front of every line.

```
sed -r 's/^\s+//g;s/\s/,/' input
1,1b0c1375c901dc8b3cc162010dc2691ca256c765
1,1b0c19c226e87899a0060e058e366fbbf4148ab4
1,1b0d1bb9f81763c679b54eac9e816a5e45dace79
1,1b0d59faa9f62150a38670c59599bdc31f3094b5
1,1b0d6a8132667ce07d7479913a85ec057331a816
```

If there are no leading blanks then following is sufficent:

```
sed -r 's/\s/,/' input
```